# VBA Code to look up function in cell, store in variable and copy somewhere else

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to come up with a script that looks up a function in named range "Hard_Constr_Cost". Saves the function in variable "HC_Baseline" and then copies it to another range.

The reason why I don't just set one range equal to another is that after the function is stored I want to run a separate loop overwriting the value in range "Hard_Constr_Cost". At the end I want to overwrite with the original function stored in the variable "HC_Baseline".

Below is the script I created so far but I'm getting an out-of-range error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub HC_Sensitivity()


Dim HC_Baseline As String


    HC_Baseline = Sheets("SU").Range("Hard_Constr_Cost").Formula
    Sheets("SU").Range("T5") = HC_Baseline

End Sub
```

Comment: Why VBA? This can be done with a simple `Match()` Excel function.

Comment: Because the script is only a small portion of the problem. There is going to be a loop overwriting "Hard_Constr_Cost" and then run a separate macro after each iteration of overwriting. At the end I want the workbook to be in its original state, therefore I need to find out at the beginning what function is in the cell (it may vary) so I can copy it back in the cell after everything is done.